# How to remove BOTH duplicates in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

Oh yes, MS Access...

I have a table that contains duplicates and essentially if there are duplicates, I need to remove BOTH records.  Is this possible?

To complicate things, what I am calling "duplicates" aren't truly duplicate across all fields, but they are across key fields.

Here's the table (not formatted very prettily):

```
ID  documentDate    accountNetAmount    reference   accountTaxAmount    getBankAccount  getCompany  isReconciled    oid
11  6/30/2013   20687.7 REFTe   0   02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    1   02364.0000000078
12  6/30/2013   -20687.7    EFTe    0   02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000079
13  6/30/2013   14935.41    REFTf   0   02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    1   02364.0000000080
14  6/30/2013   -14935.41   EFTf    0   02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000081
15  7/4/2013    -294.55 MIMOSA  -29.45  02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000177
16  7/8/2013    -1185.81    BPAY080713  -118.58 02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000499
17  7/9/2013    -462.05 PERFUME -46.2   02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000179
18  7/9/2013    -1264.09    PERFUMERY   -126.41 02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000181
```

I need to remove records where the documentDate and abs(accountNetAmount) are the same. So my result set should look like this:

```
ID  documentDate    accountNetAmount    reference   accountTaxAmount    getBankAccount  getCompany  isReconciled    oid
15  7/4/2013    -294.55 MIMOSA  -29.45  02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000177
16  7/8/2013    -1185.81    BPAY080713  -118.58 02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000499
17  7/9/2013    -462.05 PERFUME -46.2   02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000179
18  7/9/2013    -1264.09    PERFUMERY   -126.41 02537.0000000014    02544.0000000023    0   02364.0000000181
```

Any suggestions? And don't forget, MS Access... ugh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I would try grouping based on those fields that you consider important.
something like

```
SELECT documentDate, abs(accountNetAmount) , count(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY DocumentDate, abs(accountNetAmount)
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

The above query could become a view that you could then join against with your table to get the list with the duplicates removed.

Comment: Most excellent! Thanks @Nathan-Fisher, I took what you suggested and ended up with this:

    'SELECT a.ID, a.documentDate, a.reference, a.accountNetAmount, a.accountTaxAmount, a.getBankAccount, a.getCompany, a.isReconciled from GLBankOut2 a
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT sum(ID) as RowID, documentDate, abs(accountNetAmount) as acctNetAmount , accountTaxAmount, getBankAccount
    FROM GLBankOut2
    GROUP BY documentDate, abs(accountNetAmount), accountTaxAmount, getBankAccount
    HAVING count(*) = 1) b
    ON a.ID = b.RowID'